# BASH pass a variable to grep produce different result

Tags: bash, grep

Script:

```
echo $1 $n
while true 
do
  ps -aux | awk '{print $1 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $11}'  > task.log
  while IFS=' ' read r
  do 
    echo $r
  done < task.log | grep "$n" | awk '/a/{sum+=$1} END{print"Total CPU Usage:", sum}' >> monitor2.log
  sleep $1
done
```

This is a simple script to see the cpu usage by output -aux result in task.log and let grep and awk process it sum it all by entering a keyword

The problem is that the result is always when I run ./monitor1.sh 2 firefox

Total CPU Usage: 0

I tested if I put grep replace $n with firefox and not variable, the output is

Total CPU Usage: 1.1

Comment: You don't appear to **assign** variable "n"

Comment: What is the complete purpose of the whole script? What are the inputs?

Comment: May we know why the first part of your awk command is `/a/{sum+=$1}...`? Shouldn't that just be `{sum+=$2}`?

Comment: er, /a/ is nothing.... I just simply copy it from nowhere, started bash 3 days ago, complete beginner

Comment: the inputs are 1 firefox, it search the ps -aux in my desired format, output it to task.log, then read task.log and output the sum of cpu usage to monitor2.log and continuously write it with the 1 second ($1 my first input) interval

Comment: ya, the only problem is variable 'n' not success to pass to grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script:

- You nowhere assign the variable "$n", thus it is empty. Probably you mean to use `n=$2` or just use `$2` positional variable instead
- "task.log" is useless, if you want it use `tee` to pipe to it
- Doing `ps -axu` and then limiting columns with `awk` looks strange. `ps` can format the output by itself
- Parsing `ps | grep` is bad, use `pgrep` for that
- remember to quote the variables

Your script after some fixing may look like this:

```
while true; do
  cpuusage=$(
      pgrep "$2" | 
      tee >(xargs ps -aux >task.log) | 
      xargs ps -o cpu% |
      awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
  )
  echo "Total CPU Usage: $cpuusage" >> monitor2.log
  sleep "$1"
done
```

- pgrep is a better alternative to `ps -aux | grep ...`
- `xargs` passes `pgrep` outupt to `ps -o %cpu=`
- `ps -o %cpu=` prints percent cpu usage for each process
- `awk` is used to sum it.
- Then a simple echo appends to `monitor2.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're after something like this:

```
ps aux | awk '$11 ~ /firefox/{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }'
```

The `awk` checks field 11 of every row produced by `ps` and if it contains `firefox`, it executes the associated `{}` block. Beware, on different systems the `ps` outputs are different.

You want to run this within a `watch` command. Eg. like this (notice how you can avoid quoting hell with the use of awk variables).

```
ps-sum() { ps aux | awk -v regex=$1 '$11 ~ regex { sum += $3 } END { print sum }' ;}
export -f ps-sum

watch -x bash -c "ps-sum firefox"
```

Comment: I want to let it to be like whenever I type    ./monitor1.sh 1 processname(variable), I can pass the variable to the script, the problem is when I use $n to pass it to grep, the sum is 0, but when i simply run it without passing variable, example firefox or whatever, the output is correct

Comment: How did you come to a conclusion that you can use `$n`? The second argument passed by the script invocation is called simply `$2`.

Comment: And simplifying your script always leaves less space for errors, that's why I cut out only the necessary 'flesh' and left the strange bash loops behind...